# How to use different "search_method"s for jsTree in one application?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I need to use different "search_method" of jsTree. There are at least 3 functions:

- "jstree_title_contains"
- "contains"
- "jstree_contains"

FOr example if I click on the first button search_method should change to "jstree_title_contains".
If I click on the second button search_method should change to "jstree_contains".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
jstree = $.jstree._reference(root_element); // root_element is the selector for the element jstree is attached to (element.jstree({...}))
jstree._get_settings().search.search_method = 'jstree_title_contains'; // or 'contains' or 'jstree_contains'
```

Comment: So if I have an id="tree" I can just try $('#tree')._get_settings().search.search_method = 'jstree_title_contains'; Am I right ?

Comment: You have to get the reference first. Have you tried it as above?